# How to put the white block and text over an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
I need to place this white section over the image. I could not add the  diagonal shape here, that's the main problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use background with :before option CSS on your div.

Make awhite SVG with a diagonal. After, write CSS width this SVG in background and place a opacity .5 or .25.

**Example :**

```
#divText{
    position: relative;
    &:before{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: url('path/yoursvg.svg');
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: .5; /* Or .25 */
    }
}
```

With that, it should work. ;)